# UIWebView loading a local image that gets overwritten but it doesn't refresh

Tags: iphone, html, ios, image, uiwebview

My problem is this

I'm loading an html string into an UIWebView, in which i'm referencing a local image from my application's Documents folder.

```
<html><body><img src="image.png"/></body></html>
```

It loads just fine, no problems with the baseUrl or anything. The problem is when I do some stuff and generate a new image, with the same name, and save it in the same Documents folder, overwriting the old one (I delete the old one if it exists and save the new one).

Now, with the UIWebView still loaded on the screen, if I do a [webview reload] or manually load the html string again, I still get the old image, the one I have just overwritten.

I already checked in the simulator folder, the image.png there is indeed the new image, not the old one. And I already did everything imaginable to stop the webview from caching.

Of course, if I save the new image with a different name, say "image2.png", and reload the html string with src="image2.png", it all shows up ok.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Try appending a random query string to your image source.
ie.

```
function ImageSource(src){
  return src + "?time=" + (new Date()).getTime().toString();
}
function ForceImageReloads(){
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    var img = images[i];
    var s = img.getAttribute("src");
    img.src = ImageSource(s);
  }
}
ForceImageReloads();
```

Or something similar to that :)

Comment: It ain't pretty, but after a couple hours of head banging its the only thing I found that works. I guess until Apple has a better solution, this is what I got to do :)

Comment: I wouldn't hold your breath on a change to this. This has more to do with the way the web works (browser caching) than Apple internals :)

Comment: Though most browsers expose a refresh button that usually gets rid of stale data. I guess I would have thought that the reload function would do similar to a browser refresh. (Or perhaps expose something else to flush the browser cache, if reload doesn't do it.) It just seems like the UIWebview should be doing or exposing something to better handle this situation.

Comment: You would usually have to clear your cache (Which some browsers implement with a modifier key on reload). You are able to clear the browser cache in Settings -> Safari on the phone. If you are using a simulator, you can also select Reset Device from the Menu (Which is probably overkill :) )

Comment: Does this still work?  iOS8 and Xcode6 doesn't seem to cut it for me.  It reloads the image but still gives me a blank.

Comment: @RaymondArrayWang Since this is more generally related to the browser (webkit) rather than Apple specific code, I would imagine it still works. It would take effort from Apple to remove this behavior, and would probably break large parts of the web.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a problem with the simulator. I had something similar once. Try running your code on a real device. For me, the simulator seem like it is lazy to reload data that have the same name.

Comment: It does the same thing on an actual device